# Outlook how to secure yourself using imap

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I have 50 email accounts in my Outlook. 10 are current projects, and needed, 40 are terminated projects, and just costing performance. I do not want these 40 in my Outlook. But I want their file to stay on my computer, so that I can easily integrate them into Outlook when the client returns for the next project. What I am unsure of, is when I remove from Outlook, will the data file be deleted from my local machine? What format is best to use? I understood that POP3 does not save my outgoing mail on the mail server. On the other side, IMAP may not keep old mails.
P.S:
I want this to be a safe method

Comment: Are you still researching it? If you don't have questions, it's recommended to mark the helpful post to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want their file to stay on my computer, so that I can easily
> integrate them into Outlook when the client returns for the next
> project

The easiest approach is to Export the email to a PST file that is local on your computer.

Outlook, File, Open/Export:   Select the email for the account  and Export it to a PST file.

Once the email has been exported and saved in a PST file, you can keep or delete the email account (personal preference). But if you need the email previously exported, you can just open the PST file.

Exporting to a PST File is the simplest way. Take care managing PST files and make sure the files have meaningful names to avoid any confusion.

You can, if you wish, look at Auto Archiving but that is a little more complicated. Exporting to a File is an easier concept.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with John, exporting a .pst file locally is an easy and effective method, in this case,  we could open it directly in Outlook at any time.

As a supplement, we could also try to [archive your data to a pst file manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6). The obvious difference between archiving and exporting is that the archiving data would be removed from server and we could only get them from your pst file, so it's important to save your file carefully.

You could choose a method according to your need.